# Group By Result Into a List

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to list all of the rental properties a manager manages from this schema:

```
Create Table Rental_Property(property_number int Primary Key, managerId  
int, Foreign Key(managerId) References manage(managerId));
```

Here my procedure:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure supervisor_properties
As
        list_of_properties varchar (300) := ' ';
Begin
        Select 'Manager' || ': ' || managerId || ' ' || property_number
        Into list_of_properties
        From Rental_Property
        Group By managerId;
End;
```

The part I am having trouble is the procedure above `group by` will group all the tuples that have the same managerId together. Now how do I print out the results something like this:

```
Manager m1: Rental_Prop1, Rental_Prop2, Rental_Prop3
Manager m2: Rental_Prop9, Rental_Prop6, Rental_Prop4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list_agg()`:

```
    Select (managerId || ' ' ||
            list_agg(property_number, ' ') within group (order by property_number)
           )
    Into list_of_properties
    From Rental_Property
    Group By managerId;
```

The only issue is that the `into` is putting the value into a variable . . . and this will generate an error if the `group by` has multiple managers.

Start with this query:

```
Select managerId,
       list_agg(property_number, ' ') within group (order by property_number) as properties
From Rental_Property
Group By managerId;
```

EDIT:

I see.  If you want to print the values:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure supervisor_properties
As
Begin
    for x in (Select managerId,
                     list_agg(property_number, ' ') within group (order by property_number) as properties
              From Rental_Property
              Group By managerId
             )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.managerId || ' ' || x.properties);
    end loop;
End;
```

Comment: Hello, can you please explain by what you mean by "The only issue is that the into is putting the value into a variable . . . and this will generate an error if the group by has multiple managers.?" Because the `group by` will only have one managerId in each group.

Comment: @DF768 . . . That is what the `into` is doing.  Start with the second query.